# titleCasing not returning right answer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the string "Brian Wade Stacks", 
Here's the code:

```
var fixName = function(myName) {

    var partsOfName = [
    part1 = myName.substring(0, 5),
    part2 = myName.substring(5, 8),
    part3 = myName.substring(9, myName.length)
    ];

    part1 = part1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part1.slice(1);
    part2 = part2.charAt(5).toUpperCase() + part2.slice(1);
    part3 = part3.charAt(9).toUpperCase() + part3.slice(1);

    return(part1+" "+part2+" "+part3);
}


var myName= "brianwadestacks"
console.log("My name fixed is " + myName);
```

It's returning My name fixed is brianwadestacks

Comment: You've defined a function but not called it anywhere. You also have a syntax error (extra `"` after `myName`).

Comment: So instead of calling myName, call fixName?

Comment: O.k. Now I'm getting this output.
My name fixed is function (myName){
        
        var  partsOfName = [
        part1 = myName.substring(0, 5),
        part2 = myName.substring(5, 8),
        part3 = myName.substring(9, myName.length)
        ]
        part1 = part1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part1.slice(1);
        part2 = part2.charAt(5).toUpperCase() + part2.slice(1);
        part3 = part3.charAt(9).toUpperCase() + part3.slice(1);
        
return(part1+" "+part2+" "+part3);

}

Stacks...ent4.js (line 147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling `fixName`; you need to do that.

```
console.log("My name fixed is " + fixName(myName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable *partsOfName* is not used, so why create it? Also, *part1*, *part2* and *part3* are created as global variables after the function runs because they aren't declared. The substring for *part2* should extend to index 9 (it actually stops immediately before the nominated index). When selecting from an index to the end, the ending index can be omitted. Consider:

```
var part1 = myName.substring(0, 5);
var part2 = myName.substring(5, 9);
var part3 = myName.substring(9);
```

In your code:

```
> part1 = part1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part1.slice(1);
> part2 = part2.charAt(5).toUpperCase() + part2.slice(1);
> part3 = part3.charAt(9).toUpperCase() + part3.slice(1);
```

the character indexes should all be zero since you want to capitalise the first character, so:

```
part1 = part1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part1.slice(1);
part2 = part2.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part2.slice(1);
part3 = part3.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part3.slice(1);
```

Finally, don't use function expressions where declarations are indicated, there are subtle differences that will catch you out:

```
function fixName(myName) {

    var part1 = myName.substring(0, 5);
    var part2 = myName.substring(5, 9);
    var part3 = myName.substring(9);

    part1 = part1.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part1.slice(1);
    part2 = part2.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part2.slice(1);
    part3 = part3.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part3.slice(1);

    return(part1+" "+part2+" "+part3);
}

var myName= "brianwadestacks";
console.log("My name fixed is " + fixName(myName)); // My name fixed is Brian Wade Stacks
```

Comment: Sorry again I am new to coding and didn't realize what this sight was used for. Should have done more work to figure this out for myself. Thank you for all the great answers.